# Problem in checking time between 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue when searching 1 time between 2 different columns, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I have 2 different scenarios

```
Working for this one
    time_from '06:00:00'
    time_to '18:00:00'

Not working for this one
    time_from '18:00:00'
    time_to '06:00:00'
```

Because when it came to `between 18:00:00 AND 06:00:00` the date change, while I don't add dates in the database.

```
CAST('05:12:16' AS TIME)
    BETWEEN CAST(time_from AS TIME) 
    AND CAST(time_to AS TIME)
```

Please help me out with this.

**Update**
The first query is working.

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as `job_user_id`, `services`.`id` as `job_service_id`, `job_surge_settings`.`time_from`,
`job_surge_settings`.`time_to`, `jobs`.`lat`, `jobs`.`lon`
FROM `services`
LEFT JOIN `services_equipments` ON `services_equipments`.`service_id` = `services`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `service_provider_equipments` ON `service_provider_equipments`.`equipment_id` = `services_equipments`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `service_provider_equipments`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `jobs` ON `jobs`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `baskets_equipments` ON `baskets_equipments`.`equipment_id` = `services_equipments`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `baskets` ON `baskets`.`id` = `baskets_equipments`.`basket_id`
LEFT JOIN `job_surge_settings` ON `job_surge_settings`.`basket_id` = `baskets`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `state_taxes` ON `state_taxes`.`id` = `job_surge_settings`.`state_tax_id`
WHERE `services`.`id` = 4
AND `users`.`id` = 2
AND `job_surge_settings`.`id` IS NOT NULL
AND '09:52:12' BETWEEN job_surge_settings.time_from AND job_surge_settings.time_to
GROUP BY `baskets`.`name`
```

And this query is not working, when the time change to 05:52:12

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as `job_user_id`, `services`.`id` as `job_service_id`, `job_surge_settings`.`time_from`,
`job_surge_settings`.`time_to`, `jobs`.`lat`, `jobs`.`lon`
FROM `services`
LEFT JOIN `services_equipments` ON `services_equipments`.`service_id` = `services`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `service_provider_equipments` ON `service_provider_equipments`.`equipment_id` = `services_equipments`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `service_provider_equipments`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `jobs` ON `jobs`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `baskets_equipments` ON `baskets_equipments`.`equipment_id` = `services_equipments`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `baskets` ON `baskets`.`id` = `baskets_equipments`.`basket_id`
LEFT JOIN `job_surge_settings` ON `job_surge_settings`.`basket_id` = `baskets`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `state_taxes` ON `state_taxes`.`id` = `job_surge_settings`.`state_tax_id`
WHERE `services`.`id` = 4
AND `users`.`id` = 2
AND `job_surge_settings`.`id` IS NOT NULL
AND '05:52:12' BETWEEN job_surge_settings.time_from AND job_surge_settings.time_to
GROUP BY `baskets`.`name`
```

Because of the second scenario the second query not returning the data, could you please help me in fixing my query, I tried to use `IF` but I'm failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**: When `time_from` is smaller than `time_to`

```
CAST('05:12:16' AS TIME)
    BETWEEN CAST(time_from AS TIME) 
    AND CAST(time_to AS TIME)
```

**Scenario 2**: When `time_from` is greater than `time_to`

```
CAST('05:12:16'AS TIME) >= CAST(time_from  AS TIME) 
OR CAST('05:12:16' AS TIME) < CAST(time_to AS TIME)
```

Now that being said.

- If you are storing time without date in database then no need to type-cast.
- Also if you are passing input parameter in time format only which is equivalent to mysql, no need to type cast that too.
- Also you can do a `IF` condition to make it one.

**Update**:
So replace

```
AND '05:52:12' BETWEEN job_surge_settings.time_from AND job_surge_settings.time_to
```

with

```
AND IF(job_surge_settings.time_from > job_surge_settings.time_to, 
          '05:12:16' >= job_surge_settings.time_from OR '05:12:16' < job_surge_settings.time_to, 
          '05:12:16' BETWEEN job_surge_settings.time_from AND job_surge_settings.time_to
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, I tried but still, I'm getting failed. I'm updating my query in my question can you please check that and make it that correct?

Comment: so do you have two column in database `time_from` & `time_to`? and you are searching using a user input? is that so? For better understanding you should include table structure and some sample input data.

Comment: Well I'm joining alot tables, including table structure will be very hard, but for better understanding, as you said, I have 2 columns, `time_from` & `time_to` and I'm searching using a user input. Input data is let say just time.

I have updated my question please check the query there, you will better understand that.

Comment: oh if so, check my last updated query and try it in your where clause.

Comment: You are a life saver, Thank you so much